# Determine an orthogonal basis of V containing the vector (1, 0, 0, -1)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

let $V \subseteq R ^ 4$ be the vector space given by the solutions $(x, y, z, t)$ of the equation: $$x + y + z + t = 0$$

1. Determine an orthogonal basis of V containing the vector (1, 0, 0, -1).
2. Complete the base found in $a)$ in a base of $R ^ 4$

I find a basis for the equation: $(-1, 1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 1, 0), (-1, 0, 0, 1)$

I find an orthogonal basis by solving the system: $\begin{bmatrix}
-1 &1& 0& 0\\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$  from which I get: $t(1, 1, 1, 1)$, however it is not clear to me how to obtain the orthogonal vector of point 1).

Comment: Note:  $(-1,0,0,1)=-(1,0,0,-1)$

Comment: Is $V$ contained in $\mathbb{R}^4$ or in $\mathbb{R}^5$?

Comment: $V$ is contained In $R^4$

Comment: You can just use Gram-Schmidt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly found a basis of $V$, however it is not an orthogonal basis. Moreover $t(1,1,1,1)$ is the orthogonal complement of $V$, where $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

If $v_0=(1,0,0,-1)$ is in your basis $B_V$, then you have to find two more vectors that are linear independent and also orthogonal.

1. To find the first vector $v_1=(a,b,c,d)$ consider $v_1\cdot v_0=a-d=0$ and $v_1\in V$.
2. To find the second vector $v_2$ consider $v_2\cdot v_0=0$ , $v_2\cdot v_1=0$ and $v_2\in V$.